# How to Change XAML Theme in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am using Mahh.Apps.Metro for User Interface, and that utility has some themes to change with.

I can able to change theme, but when I am using Brush, the changed theme is not reflecting in the Window. But if I modify the XAML code of all controls and add these instead of Brush, the theme color changes.

**Doesn't Work**

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentBrush}"/>
```

**Works**

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Also, I am loading some Icons made of XAML Path from a different assembly `Mahh.Apps.Metro.Resources' I have add DynamicResource for Path fill color, but that doesn't seems to work on theme change.

**Current Result**

[image: Current Result]

**Expected Result**

[image: Expected]

***Further Info***
I am adding all my resources in App.xaml file

Comment: I think we're talking about two different issues here. Can you raise an issue and small repro [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/)  as I need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this discussion and you might find an answer - https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/190

Personally, I have had a some issues related to themes/binding in MA. M which can only be solved by contributing to the project.

Comment: I have made a lot of changes to MA.M on my personal project. Which I consumed in the sample above. Only Issue now is DynamicBinding in Metro.Resources dll are not updated.